# Cannot return to portrait mode after pressing fullscreen icon in YoutubePlayerFragment

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, youtube-api

I'm learning to add a youtube video on my fragment, everything is fine until I press fullscreen. After exiting fullscreen, the screen is in landscape mode.

FragmentTwo.java code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_two, container, false);
    textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_title);
    YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();
    youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(getString(R.string.youtube_api_key), this);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_video, youTubePlayerFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    //Get the title of the video 
    textView.setText(getArguments().getString("1"));
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
    if(!b) {
        youTubePlayer.cueVideo(getArguments().getString("8"));
    }
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And my .xml file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/youtube_frame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.gameapp.FragmentTwo">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_video"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250sp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/frame_video"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried setting all the layouts' orientation to "vertical" but nothing happens. I have to press back button to get rid of it, which is too much inconvient. Can someone show me how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, can someone helps me

Comment: I have used ` mYouTubePlayer.setFullscreenControlFlags(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_SYSTEM_UI);` It will open youtube in full screen in portrait mode.Hope it helps